# Ionic Pro - ionic link fails

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a paid subscription to Ionic Pro.

Running ionic link fails with the following error:

> [ERROR] API request was successful, but the response format was
>   unrecognized.
>
> ```
> Request: GET https://api.ionicjs.com/apps/<<app_id>>
> Response: 200
> Body: ........
> ```

Backend is set to pro. 
I did try with legacy as well but that failed. 
I tried logging out and back in, in both legacy and pro. 
I also tried updating ionic, and clearing the node modules.

---

Environment Details:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.0.6 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)

Ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.1.6

---